# Next greater or lesser number than ARG in a list of integers

Tags: list, numbers

In this example, there is a list of integers `'(2527 1771 2107 2317)`.  The variable `arg` is an integer, which may or may not be one of the integers in the list.  **Q**:  How can an Emacs user programmatically return the next greater or lesser number than `arg` in the list?

**Example #1**:   `(my-func 2150 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'greater)` => `2317`

**Example #2**:   `(my-func 2150 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'lesser)` => `2107`

**Example #3**:   `(my-func 3000 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'greater)` => `nil`

**Example #4**:   `(my-func 3000 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'lesser)` => `2527`

**Example #5**:   `(my-func 1000 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'greater)` => `1771`

**Example #6**:   `(my-func 1000 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'lesser)` => `nil`

**Example #7**:   `(my-func 2107 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'greater)` => `2317`

**Example #8**:   `(my-func 2107 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'lesser)` => `1771`

**Example #9**:   `(my-func 2527 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'greater)` => `nil`

**Example #10**:   `(my-func 2527 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'lesser)` => `2317`

**Example #11**:   `(my-func 1771 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'greater)` => `2107`

**Example #12**:   `(my-func 1771 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) 'lesser)` => `nil`

Comment: What happens on equality?

Comment: @NickD  -- thank you ... I'll add a few examples to address equality.

Comment: Either you have a known sorted list (in which case you can stop looking once you cross the threshold -- but your example lists are not sorted), or else you must compare against every list item.  It's simple iteration either way -- I'm sure you can write a trivial `dolist` solution yourself?

Comment: @phils -- thank you ... I had thought there may be a function that already does this.  If not, then I will create something in the next 24 to 48 hours if there is no answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by `lesser` and `greater` you mean something like `<` and `>`, this seems to do what you ask.

```lisp
(defun my-func (num nbs pred)
  (let (ans)
    (dolist (nb  nbs)
      (when (and (funcall pred nb num)  
                 (or (not ans)  (not (funcall pred nb ans))))
        (setq ans  nb)))
    ans))

(my-func 2150 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'>) ; => 2317
(my-func 2150 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'<) ; => 2107
(my-func 3000 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'>) ; => nil
(my-func 3000 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'<) ; => 2527
(my-func 1000 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'>) ; => 1771
(my-func 1000 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'<) ; => nil
(my-func 2107 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'>) ; => 2317
(my-func 2107 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'<) ; => 1771
(my-func 2527 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'>) ; => nil
(my-func 2527 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'<) ; => 2317
(my-func 1771 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'>) ; => 2107
(my-func 1771 '(2527 1771 2107 2317) #'<) ; => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a more FP-style version:

```
(require 'dash) ; for `-first' and `-rpartial'

(defun nearest-inequality (comparand numbers-set comparator)
  (-first
   (-rpartial comparator comparand)
   (sort numbers-set (assoc-default comparator '((< . >) (> . <))))))
```